# Is there a "Favourites" section or equivalent in Visual Studio to facilitate the location of regularly opened files?

Tags: visual-studio

Someone asked the question "I have a Visual Studio solution with many projects; how can I organise them so I can easily find the projects I work most on?" ( [Favorite projects in big solution in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734206/favorite-projects-in-big-solution-in-visual-studio)
)

My question is similar: I have a (C++) project with many files across many filters and it's cumbersome to locate certain files that I use a lot. Is there a *favourites* or equivalent that I can reference these oft opened files so that finding them is a breeze?

Your help is much appreciated!

--Edit--
BTW I'm using VS2008 at work and VS2010 at home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention what version of VS you're using, but [this add-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00f3b972-cb54-47f2-ac56-b2f48c77a74d/) looks promising for 2005 and 2008.

Or there's [this one](http://www.svprogramming.net/favorite-documents/index.html) for 2010!

Comment: Sir, this indeed looks promising. Not sure how installing add-ins will be at work but great answer for home :)